# Url shortener which displays shortlink in address bar?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm wondering if there is a URL shortener which, which clicked on, keeps displaying the actual shortened link in the address bar, as opposed to showing the original URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a full-height iframe, but many sites use `X-Frame-Options` to forbid this (including major ones like Facebook and Google). Users would see an error message for these sites.

Ow.ly and others [used to use this technique](http://blog.hootsuite.com/htly-owly/), but most have ditched it by now for this reason. In general, it's considered user-hostile and a Bad Idea™ now.